# How to exit code if nothing is entered? Code example: Check if string is a palindrome or not? (in C Programming Language)

Tags: c

QUESTION: How to exit code if nothing is entered into STDIN (console)?

For example:

***Input**
"NULL - NOTHING - ZERO" :)

**Expected Output**
(Close program quit loop)*

---

**Input:**

Hello

**Output:**

Hello is not a palindrome

---

**Input:**

otto

**Output:**

otto is a palindrome

---

Code Explanation:
A palindrome is a string phrase that reads the same backwards as well as forwards. Examples of palindromes are “ABCDCBA”, “otto”, “i am ma i”, “C”. Write a program that reads in a line of text, and prints out whether or not that line of text is a palindrome.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN 100

void reverseString(char *str, char *reversedStr)
{
    int i;

    for (i=strlen(str)-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        *reversedStr++ = *(str+i);
    }
    *reversedStr = '\0';
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char str[MAXLEN];
    char reversedStr[MAXLEN];

    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str)-1, stdin) != NULL)
    {
        str[strlen(str)-1] = '\0'; // the last character is the newline. Replace with null
        reverseString(str, reversedStr);
        if (strcmp(str, reversedStr) == 0)
            printf("%s is a palindrome\n", str);
        else {
            printf("%s is not a palindrome\n", str);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Code Snippet:
https://onlinegdb.com/ByGKe8LnE

Comment: in your code, if the user enters nothing and then presses enter, then the only character is the newline before you replace it with null terminator. so you can check if that's the only character before you replace, and that's how you know if the user did not enter anything.

Comment: Comparing the return value of `fgets` to `'\0'` doesn't make sense, since you're comparing a pointer to the null byte.  Instead, compare it to the null *pointer*, i.e.  `while (fgets(...) != NULL)`.  Then it should do what you intended.

Comment: @TomKarzes thanks thats actually in the original code, but edited it it to see if that would effect the code

Comment: @ChrisRollins how would you implement that into the code?

Comment: Your code works. Just press ctrl-d right after enter (signals end of input) to exit.

Comment: @niry thanks that's a good point, freel free to add that as an answer...

Comment: I would check if the length (as computed by strlen) of the inputted string is exactly 1 (before you replace the \n with a \0). because if the user enters nothing and presses enter, the string will be "\n\0", it can't be anything else with how your code is written.

Comment: I mean I guess after replacing you can check if strlen returns 0 and it would also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works. Just press ctrl-d right after enter (signals end of input) to exit.

Couple of other things:

- `fgets()` doesn't need size minus 1. per the manual: "`fgets()` reads in at most one less than size characters..."
- there is really no need to copy/reverse the entire string and compare, half will suffice, OR you could simply compare beginning with end until center, without copying.
- `strlen()` "walks" the string - you can reuse the result of it instead of calling again.

.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN 100

int isPalindrome(char *str, size_t len) {
    char *end = str + len - 1;
    while (end > str)
        if (*end-- != *str++) return 0;
    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char str[MAXLEN];
    while (fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin) != NULL) {
        size_t len = strlen(str) - 1;
        str[len] = 0; // the last character is the newline. Replace with null char
        printf("%s is %sa palindrome\n", str, isPalindrome(str, len) ? "" : "not ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```